# How to access UITableView subview selection?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I've created a `UIViewController` (`AnestDrugCalcViewController`) that has a button that opens a `UITableViewController` (`DrugTableViewController`) to select a drug. The `DrugTableViewController` is populated based on a `NSMutableArray` and is made up of several `NSDictionary` objects (drugName, drugDose, drugConcentration, etc.).

I'm able to open `DrugTableViewController` by pushing it onto the navigation stack, but I can't figure out how to tell from my `AnestDrugCalcViewController` what the properties of the selected item are.

```
//  DrugTableViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DrugTableViewController : UITableViewController {
NSMutableArray          *drugList;
NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath;
IBOutlet UITableView    *myTableView;
NSObject *selectedDrug;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *drugList;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *myTableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSObject *selectedDrug;

@end
```

Top of DrugTableViewController.m
    #import "DrugTableViewController.h"

```
@implementation DrugTableViewController

@synthesize drugList,myTableView, selectedDrug;
```

Comment: Is vwCalc a UIView, or is it a UIViewController?

Comment: vwCalc is a UIViewController. vwDrugTable is a UITableViewController

Answer (score 3):

You could have a property in `vwDrugTable` that stores the the selected row when the user selects it. Then, after that table view is removed and you are back in `vwCalc`, just get the data from that property.

So that means in `vwDrugTable`, have something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.selectedDrug = [self.drugs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Then just access `selectedDrug` from `vwCalc` when you need it.

Comment: Sorry -- I'm a noob -- 
The two views have separate view controllers. 
I've created selectedDrug as an NSObject and can access it from vwDrugTable, but how do I access it from vwCalc? 
I've included DrugTableViewController.h in CalculatorViewController.m and have defined the drugListViewController as a local variable (also including @property in .h and @synthesize in .m).

When I try to access the property (NSLog(@"%@"),drugListViewController.selectedDrug), it refuses to compile ("request for member 'selectedDrug' in somthing not a structure or union)

What am I missing? 

I a

Comment: Edit your question and show me your .h and top of your .m (where @synthesize sits) for DrugTableViewController. That will help me help you.

Answer (score 3):

`UITableView`'s `-indexPathForSelectedRow` method will allow you to determine which row is selected:

```
NSIndexPath *selectionPath = [vwDrugTable indexPathForSelectedRow];
if (index) {
    NSLog(@"Selected row:%u in section:%u", [selectionPath row], [selectionPath section]);
} else {
    NSLog(@"No selection");
}
```

To be notified when the selection changes, implement `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` in your table view delegate:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Selection Changed");
}
```

Comment: Also, hungarian notation is not recommended in Objective-C.